# ASP.NET App Settings Directly in Markup

Tags: asp.net, markup, appsettings

What is the syntax for accessing a AppSettings directly from the ASP.NET Markup? I can't remember exactly, but it was something like '<%= $.settingname %>'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<%$ AppSettings:SettingName %>'